# Get zoom and center to fit all markers in a google static map

Tags: google-maps, java-me, midp

I'm working in a Java Me application that uses google static maps. The problem is that I need to get the zoom and center that fits all markers, and I need to add some labels in some coordinates on the map. How can I do this? I need a function in the server or in the midlet to get this parameters, I can't use javascript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to calculate it on your own.

When you supply markers, usually the map will have a viewport to show all markers.

To modify the viewport use the [visible](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#Viewports)-parameter.

---

**Referring to the comments:**
Pseudo-Code for calculating the center from a couple of Points:

**latitude:** `(maxLatOfAllPoints+minLatOfAllPoints)/2`
**longitude:**`(maxLngOfAllPoints+minLngOfAllPoints)/2`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I need to get the center in the mobile application to be able to paint some labels in the map.

Comment: When you know the positions of the markers it needs a little bit mathematics to calculate the center(see above)

Comment: I came here searching for this, documentation URL should now be: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro?hl=en#Viewports

Answer (score 9):

I have had the same problem. Don't use "&zoom=xx" in your url, the map will auto-fit for all your markers!

Comment: For me does not works. The `&zoom=xx` parameter needs to be on the url.

Answer (score -2):

1. Define bounds object

   ```
   bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   ```
2. When you create and place marker on the map extend bondes with marker position.

   ```
   bounds.extend(mPosition);
   ```

   where `mPosition` is a google `new google.maps.LatLng(0,0)` object, the same that you use during marker creation.
3. at the end ot you can create a link for click or just run.

   ```
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
   ```

That is it.

Comment: OP is asking for a static map, not the interactive one that this is for